# Get property programmatically and evaluate it with SPEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file, spring-expression-language

I am trying to mimic the `@Value` annotation programmatically by retrieving a property from the properties file using `Environment` and then evaluate the expression using `SpelExpressionParser`.

Here is a code snippet:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class Test {
    private String dynamicSPELStr = "#{${test.spel.map}.default}";

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    void testSPEL() {
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        log.info("[PARSER] {}", parser
                .parseExpression(environment.resolvePlaceholders(dynamicSPELStr))
                .getValue());
    }
}
```

and the property is: `test.spel.map={default: '5', key1: '10', key2: '20', key3: '40'}`

However I am receiving the following error:

```
Expression [#{{default: '5', key1: '10', key2: '20', key3: '40'}.default}] @1: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'
```

Running the same expression using `@Value` works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` attribute of a `@Value` annotation is not a SpEL expression. It *supports* placeholders using `${...}`, and it *supports* SpEL expressions using `#{...}`.

It is only the text between `#{` and `}` that is a SpEL expression. As such, remove the `#{` and `}` from the `dynamicSPELStr` string:

```java
private String dynamicSPELStr = "${test.spel.map}.default";
```

---

*Explanation of error*

SpEL expressions use `#variableName` to access a *variable* (see [SpEL documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions), section [4.3.10. Variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-ref-variables)).

Since the beginning of `dynamicSPELStr` is `#{`, the expression parser is complaining that the `#` variable prefix isn't followed by a valid name-character, hence the error *"Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'"*

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's more clear. Now I am receiving a different error: `EL1008E: Property or field 'default' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' - maybe not public or not valid?
`. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: @MihaiCatalinValentin No, but try `['default']` instead of `.default`